# Sample size calculation with only variance

Tags: multiple-regression, variance, sample-size

if I need to calculate the sample size for a study containing a target group (HIV+) and control group (HIV-), and I have found in the literature only the variance R^2 using a multiple regression analysis. Is there a certain formula that I could use to calculate the sample size using this variance that I found in the literature?
Thank you.

Comment: $R^2$ is not usually a variance

Comment: For certain kinds of planned tests, there are such formulas, but $R^2$ would be one of several ingredients: you need to stipulate a test size and power, too. You also need to describe the sample design: $R^2$ has a different meaning for this purpose for observational data compared to experimental data.